# Need senior help to verify my understanding about Surrogate key in relational database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship

I would like to know if my understanding about Surrogate key is correct or not.

E.g:

Below is my example database design

```
Customers Table

| id(PK) |  Name   |    Age       |   
|  1     |  John   |  34          |
|  2     |  Doe    |  30          | 

QrCodes Table
| id(PK) |  QRcode | Tracking No. | CustomerID (FK)
|  1     |  QR123  |  TR901111    |   1
|  2     |  QR345  |  TR902222    |   2


Redemptions Table
| id(PK) | Name          | Tracking No. | CustomerID(FK)
|  1     |  Redemption 1 |   TR901111   |  1
|  2     |  Redemption 2 |   TR902222   |  2
|  3     |  Rdemption  3 |   TR902222   |  2
```

As you can see,I have two Tracking No. column,one for qrcodes table & one for redemptions table. So then I can have a query like find all Qrcodes & redemptions by tracking no only.

Is the Tracking No. column can be classify as Surrogate key? or is that incorrect?

Comment: No. On the assumption that a tracking numbers are unique and permanent, then in the QrCodes table the id column is the surrogate, and the tracking no. is a UNIQUE [NATURAL] key

Comment: I don't get it at all sir. Is that means the id column in QrCodes table does not invisible / being used in the system ?

Comment: A Foreign Key should always reference a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: A SURROGATE key is a unique identifier that is NOT derived from application data. As Tracking No. is part of the application data, then it is a NATURAL key. The SURROGATE keys are the id fields you have marked as primary keys - as they are not derived from the application data. The SURROGATE keys do not need to be invisible to the outside world. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: Okay I think I'm almost got it,so the tracking No. column is the business key (non-unique) and the auto incremented(MYSQL db) ID column is the surrogate / primary key .right?

Comment: If the Tracking No is unique & permanent (in the sense that it uniquely identifies whatever is being tracked & will not be reused to track something else at a later date or deleted - as per Strawberry's original comment) then that is correct.

Comment: Please understand it's best to also describe the reality that you've modelled here. Inferring from this limited data set can easily lead to wrong assumptions. Check the first paragraph of this article to see the difference between surrogate and natural keys (either of which can be a primary key): https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/01/surrogate-keys-vs-natural-keys-for-primary-key/

Answer (score 1):

It's getting a bit confused in the comments but they're basically right (upticks for all). What you need to do is drop TrackingId from Redemptions and add QrCodeId as an FK to the QrCode table.

If each QrCode has a unique TrackingId (I think this is the case) then it should have a Unique Index, but the PK is the Id. But without understanding what you're modelling it's difficult to say definitely.